# Extract fields and substrings and merge sorted lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file consisting of 5 tab separated fields (irrelevant fields are empty in this example).

```
1       2       URL                     email               5

                https://www.a.com/t     a@b.com
                https://www.a.com       a@b.com
                https://www.b.fr        c@hl.com
                https://www.b.fr/s/faq  a@hl.com
```

Desired output:

```
domain          email(s)    
        
a.com           a@b.com
b.fr            c@hl.com, a@hl.com
```

Steps:

1. Isolate column 3 and 4

```c
awk -F "\t" '{print $3 "\t\t" $4}'
```

This yields what is shown in the first block above.

How do I go on from here?

I know how to grep the domain only, but the isolated domains don't help much in achieving the desired output lines.

I am not restricted to `awk`, it was just the only tool I knew that could isolate fields easily (via the `-F` flag).

Comment: Note that it's a mistake to just remove all but the last two elements from a domain name.   The domain registries for most countries only issue domains with at least three parts - e.g. example.net.au or example.co.uk.   Stripping them back to just `net.au` or `co.uk` is as useful as stripping `a.com` back to just `com`  (i.e. not very).    It's usually more useful to just remove common prefixes like `www.`, `mail.`, `ftp.` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk` and GNU `datamash`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="\t" }
  NR>2{                       # skip first two records
    split($3, a, "/" )        # split $3 into array a on /
    domain=a[3]               # 3rd element is the domain name
    sub(/^www\./, "", domain) # remove www. prefix
    print domain, $4          # print domain and email
  }
' file | datamash -g 1 unique 2
```

The `awk` part prints the domain and email for all records skipping the first two lines. This would be

```
a.com   a@b.com
a.com   a@b.com
b.fr    c@hl.com
b.fr    a@hl.com
```

The output is then piped to `datamash` to group the input on the first field and print a comma-separated list of unique values of the second field.

Output:

```
a.com   a@b.com
b.fr    a@hl.com,c@hl.com
```

The header line is left as exercise.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays and `gensub()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR>1 { d2e[gensub(/[^.]+\.([^.]+\.[^./]+).*/,"\\1",1,$3)][$4] }
END {
    print "domain", "emails(s)"
    for (domain in d2e) {
        cnt = 0
        for (email in d2e[domain]) {
            row = (cnt++ ? row ", " : domain OFS) email
        }
        print row
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
domain  emails(s)
a.com   a@b.com
b.fr    c@hl.com, a@hl.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) (with a little help from sed):

```
$ mlr --prepipe 'sed "/^$/d"' --tsv   put -q -S '
  $domain = joinv(mapexcept(splitnvx(joinv(mapselect(splitnvx($URL,"/"),3),""),"."),1),".");
  @e[$domain] = mapsum(@e[$domain],{$email:1});
  end {
    for(k,v in @e){@{email(s)}[k] = joink(v,",")};
    emit @{email(s)}, "domain"
  }' File.tsv
domain  email(s)
a.com   a@b.com
b.fr    c@hl.com,a@hl.com
```

The sed `--prepipe` command just removes the extaneous empty line, so that the input is parsable as TSV. The `$domain` variable is obtained by splitting the `URL` field twice, first on `/` (selecting the 3rd element) then on `.` (selecting all except the 1st element, ex. `www`). Then the out-of-stream map `@e` is constructed as a *map* of the `email` fields - this is the step that de-duplicates emails for the same domain. At the `end`, convert the email maps to comma-delimited strings and emit them.

Comment: It appears that  miller is turning out to be quite a Swiss army knife of text processing.

Answer (score 1):

here's a go at it:

```
cat inputfile |
awk '{
    match($3, "^https?://.*\\.([^./]+\\.[^./]+)", matches);
    print(matches[1], $4)
}' |
sort |
uniq |
awk '{
    domains[$1] = domains[$1] " " $2;
}
END {
    for (d in domains) {
        printf("%-15s ", d);
        $0 = domains[d];
        for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) {
            printf("%s, ", $i);
        };
        print($NF);
    };
}'
```

The first awk matches the trailing foo.bar component of the domain, followed by the email.  Filtering through `sort | uniq` eliminates duplicate domain/email combos, and makes sure the results are in domain-order, but we still have to join on the domain field and combine the matching emails with commas, so the second awk just keeps appending emails to a dictionary keyed by domain (using concatenation, with a space in-between).  Then at the end we iterate through all the emails and print them with a trailing comma, unless it's the last domain, where we don't want a comma so we just make the second-to-last the iterate-stop, and print the last field (`$NF`) by itself at conclusion.

I tried using one awk script with a two-dimensional `array[domain][email]` but wasn't getting very far because I think they're only simulated in awk, ie one cannot do `for (d in domain) { for (e in d[email]) }` with awk.  So I resorted to the shell filter.

I also don't like the hacky string concatenation loops which will become ridiculous with large numbers of emails in a domain.  But, it should work if you have just thousands; a better method should be used for millions, etc.

I picked 15 char field for domain arbitrarily.  You could remove the field length if you don't need them aligned.  You'll need a `BEGIN {}` print if you want to print a header row...

the output looks like this given your inputs from the question:

```
a.com           a@b.com
b.fr            a@hl.com, c@hl.com
```

(with dummy data added for fields 1 and 2 which you left blank; those fields must contain actual data without whitespace for the script to work, otherwise you need a field separator like tab or comma in the input file)

Comment: You don't need `cat`. `awk` sends the data to stdout so it can just be run with the file as an argument.

Comment: sure, not needed, but doesn't hurt anything, and starts the pipeline with the inputfile, which looks cleaner to me.  I developed it on one line iteratively.  most of the semicolons are also unnecessary when there are newlines.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the input file is. The command is being used unnecessarily. You also don't need to pipe `sort` into `unique` as `sort` already has a `-u` switch that does the same thing. Even that isn't needed as `awk` can already do it so there's no need to use `awk` twice.

Comment: as a pipeline it reads better to me with the input first, and doesn't add a perceptible overhead. `sort | uniq` vs `sort -u` (habit from piping to `uniq -c`) doesn't add any either, tested on 500M of duplicated english dictionaries.  but thanks for pointing those out. 
 will be glad to see a shorter version in pure awk.

Comment: Regarding `otherwise you need a field separator like tab or...` - the OP said `I have a file consisting of 5 tab separated fields`.

Comment: If you want to start a command line with the name of the file being opened, just do `< file command` instead of `cat file | command`. Doing that does hurt in general though as it takes away awks ability to populate the immensely useful `FILENAME` variable.

Comment: never knew about `< file command`, interesting! always thought a redirection had to follow the command, but it makes sense now that it can occur anywhere on the command line.  your answer is great, I was unable to make 2-dimensional array work right even with gawk but your example looks straightforward

Comment: +1 for the effort put in to the answer. And if you follow the advise prescribed by the awk experts to you, the solution will be a shining example of how to approach a problem using the awk utility as your documentation anyway is quite extensive

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be tackled via constructing a dictionary keyed on the third field(actually a portion of it) and whose corresponding value is a `set` where the fourth field gets thrown in. The usefulness of a `set` is that it keeps it's elements intrinsically unique , so we don't have to extend our efforts in any sort of programming calisthenics to keep the values unique.

```
python3 -c 'import sys
ifile = sys.argv[1]
fs = ofs = "\t"
d = {}

with open(ifile) as fh:
  for i,l in enumerate(fh,1):
    if i < 3: continue
    x,x,y,email,x = l.split(fs)
    domain = y.split("/")[2].split(".",1)[1]
    if domain in d:
      d[domain].add(email)
    else:
      d[domain] = { email }

print(f"domain{ofs}email(s)",
      *[k+ofs+", ".join(v) for k,v in d.items()],
      sep="\n")
' file
domain  email(s)
a.com   a@b.com
b.fr    a@hl.com, c@hl.com
```